# Problema com excesso casas Decimais!

Tags: python, python-3.x, conversão-de-tipo

Inicialmente eu estava desenvolvendo um Código em python que iria me ajudar a compreender melhor a Teoria dos números de Nikola Tesla([video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kQ-bbO4v5BY)).

Explicando rapidinho, começando por 360, somando cada valor separado resulta em 9, por exemplo :3 + 6 + 0 = 9 , sempre dividindo o valor 360  por 2 , somando os números separados sempre resulta em 9, por exemplo: 360/2= 180,
1+8+0 = 9    180/2 = 90     9+0 = 9   E  assim por diante

Incialmente o código base que eu fiz foi este em python

```
real_valor=360 ; string_valor=str(real_valor); valor_unitario=[]; soma_unitaria=0
for i in string_valor:
    if i == '.':
        continue
valor_unitario.append(int(i))
print(valor_unitario)
for g in valor_unitario:
    soma_unitaria += g
print(soma_unitaria)
```

Usando o primeiro como base, conclui este aqui :

```
soma_unitaria=0; from time import sleep
while True:
    sleep(0.5)
    if soma_unitaria == 0:
        real_valor = 360; string_valor = str(real_valor); valor_unitario = []
    else:
        string_valor='';soma_unitaria = 0; real_valor /= 2; string_valor = (str(real_valor)); valor_unitario.clear()
    for numero in string_valor:
        if numero == '.':
            continue
        valor_unitario.append(int(numero))
    for valor in valor_unitario:
        soma_unitaria += valor
    print("Valor Inicial : {}\nSoma dos valores unitarios divido : {}\n".format(real_valor, soma_unitaria))
```

O código Funciona inicialmente.
O problema começa apôs muitas casas decimais, não consigo converter o valor que os floats atribuem para numero float ou int (os valores inicialmente estão em string para eu separa-los um por um e conseguir somar os mesmos)

Erro linha 11

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Como posso resolver este problema, muitas casas decimais acabam adicionando o valor e , que em strings eu não consigo converter para numeros?

Answer (score 0):

Há uma diferença entre o Python2 e o Python3 que leva a esse erro:

Com o Python2, por exemplo, o int (str (5/2)) fornece 2. Com o Python3, o mesmo acontece com você: ValueError: literal inválido para int () com base 10: '2.5'

Se você precisar converter alguma string que possa conter float ao invés de int, você pode usar a seguinte fórmula :

```
int (float (myStr))
```

Como float ('3.0') e float ('3') fornecem 3.0, mas int ('3.0') dá o erro.

Comment: Eu estou pegando cada valor isolado, por exemplo 3.14 , estou armazenando em listas [1,3,4] e somando os valores separadamente 3+1+4, o problema se dá por haver um limite de casas decimais, aonde passa a ser adicionado nummeros e são adicionado letras e não é possivel converter estas letras para int ou floats, a minha duvida é se há alguma forma de tirar esse limite que o python instipula